# Django Elastic serach deleting some documents when pointing multiple documents to the same index

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have my django application where i am using django_elasticsearch_dsl to index document to later do elastic search with them. I have two similar models in database so i want the documents to be pointing to the same index in elastic search so later i can do a search with both of them like they are the same.

Righ now my setup is like this

```
@registry.register_document
class HelpCenterDocument(Document):
    title = TextField()
    url = ESTextField('get_absolute_url')
    site_id = ESIntegerField('site_id')

    class Index:
        name = 'global-search-page-index'

    class Django:
        model = HelpCenterPage
        fields = ['title', 'content']


@registry.register_document
class PageDocument(Document):
    title = TextField()
    url = TextField('get_public_url')

    class Index:
        name = 'global-search-page-index'

    class Django:
        model = Page
```

When i do manage.py search_index --rebuild it will say that it created
Indexing 90 'HelpCenterPage' objects
Indexing 213 'Page' objects

So with this my index should have 303 documents, this is not the case when i look at the count it shows i have

```
"docs": {
                "count": 239,
                "deleted": 64
            },
```

If i comment one of the @registry.register_document the count will be ok, but if i let both of them uncommented it will index only some of them

These are the index stats

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 239,
        "deleted": 64
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 1016020
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 303,
        "index_time_in_millis": 113,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 0,
        "query_time_in_millis": 0,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 0,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_docs": 0,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 20,
        "total_time_in_millis": 364,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 0,
        "periodic": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 15,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_count": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0,
        "cache_size": 0,
        "cache_count": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 10,
        "memory_in_bytes": 22757,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 16337,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 3160,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 2560,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 20,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 680,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 303,
        "size_in_bytes": 896325,
        "uncommitted_operations": 303,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 896325,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 62615
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 239,
        "deleted": 64
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 1016020
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 303,
        "index_time_in_millis": 113,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 0,
        "query_time_in_millis": 0,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 0,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 0,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_docs": 0,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 20,
        "total_time_in_millis": 364,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 0,
        "periodic": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 15,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total_count": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0,
        "cache_size": 0,
        "cache_count": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 10,
        "memory_in_bytes": 22757,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 16337,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 3160,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 2560,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 20,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 680,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 303,
        "size_in_bytes": 896325,
        "uncommitted_operations": 303,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 896325,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 62615
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "global-search-page-index": {
      "uuid": "F8-MzvZMTheadg4oE-gv4w",
      "primaries": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 239,
          "deleted": 64
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 1016020
        },
        "indexing": {
          "index_total": 303,
          "index_time_in_millis": 113,
          "index_current": 0,
          "index_failed": 0,
          "delete_total": 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
          "delete_current": 0,
          "noop_update_total": 0,
          "is_throttled": false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
          "total": 0,
          "time_in_millis": 0,
          "exists_total": 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
          "missing_total": 0,
          "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
          "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 0,
          "query_time_in_millis": 0,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 0,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
          "current": 0,
          "current_docs": 0,
          "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total": 0,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_docs": 0,
          "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
        },
        "refresh": {
          "total": 20,
          "total_time_in_millis": 364,
          "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
          "total": 0,
          "periodic": 0,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "warmer": {
          "current": 0,
          "total": 15,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total_count": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 0,
          "cache_size": 0,
          "cache_count": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "fielddata": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
          "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
          "count": 10,
          "memory_in_bytes": 22757,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes": 16337,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 3160,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes": 2560,
          "points_memory_in_bytes": 20,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 680,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
          "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
          "operations": 303,
          "size_in_bytes": 896325,
          "uncommitted_operations": 303,
          "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 896325,
          "earliest_last_modified_age": 62615
        },
        "request_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 0
        },
        "recovery": {
          "current_as_source": 0,
          "current_as_target": 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 239,
          "deleted": 64
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 1016020
        },
        "indexing": {
          "index_total": 303,
          "index_time_in_millis": 113,
          "index_current": 0,
          "index_failed": 0,
          "delete_total": 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
          "delete_current": 0,
          "noop_update_total": 0,
          "is_throttled": false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
          "total": 0,
          "time_in_millis": 0,
          "exists_total": 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
          "missing_total": 0,
          "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
          "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 0,
          "query_time_in_millis": 0,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 0,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
          "current": 0,
          "current_docs": 0,
          "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total": 0,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_docs": 0,
          "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
        },
        "refresh": {
          "total": 20,
          "total_time_in_millis": 364,
          "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
          "total": 0,
          "periodic": 0,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "warmer": {
          "current": 0,
          "total": 15,
          "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "total_count": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 0,
          "cache_size": 0,
          "cache_count": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "fielddata": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
          "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
          "count": 10,
          "memory_in_bytes": 22757,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes": 16337,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 3160,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes": 2560,
          "points_memory_in_bytes": 20,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 680,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
          "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
          "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
          "operations": 303,
          "size_in_bytes": 896325,
          "uncommitted_operations": 303,
          "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 896325,
          "earliest_last_modified_age": 62615
        },
        "request_cache": {
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 0,
          "hit_count": 0,
          "miss_count": 0
        },
        "recovery": {
          "current_as_source": 0,
          "current_as_target": 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```